# How to add +1 value to an update_post_meta function

Tags: php, string, wordpress, math, integer

If this variable is dynamically set as $newsales_countday = 10. The below command will update the post meta key sales_countday, and give it a value of '10'

```
update_post_meta ( $productId, 'sales_countday', $newsales_countday ) ;
```

What I want to know is how can you just +1 to that value, so that it can be 11 instead.

I'm not good at php, so i tried saying

```
$addone = 1 ;
```

and then

```
update_post_meta ( $productId, 'sales_countday', $newsales_countday + $addone ) ;
```

But I think I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: We normally expect users to consult the manual first. No offence please if you see downvotes and closes, it's just that. Doing simple math operation is normally inherently available inside a programming language so we expect users to look that up in the reference as for example next time you wonder about how to substract one and then. You understand?

Comment: http://php.net/language.operators.arithmetic - http://php.net/language.operators.increment - the missing links as it seems that even those who answer don't give it to you which kind of is a shame and not very welcoming for a new user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to declare a new variable for that operation, simply put `$newsales_countday + 1`.
As a response to the answers specifying that you should use `$newsales_countday++`, that is **wrong** unless you do it **before** the call of the method, since `$myvar++` returns the original value and then increments it.

```
$num = 4;
echo $num++; //Will echo 4, then increment $num to 5
echo $num;   //Will echo 5
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

$newsales_countday++

Answer (score -1):

```
$newsales_countday++
```

Is the easiest way and most useful option.